# IndexError: list index out of range into a nested loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a code that reads an input file, which is an xyz file, take each atom that i need and calculates the distance between the atoms, this the code:

```
  lines = ['SOL','DP','DT', 'DG', 'DA', 'DC', '4', '5', '6', 'NA', 'OW' ]

for record in fo_lines:
  line = record.split()
  if ((line[3] == lines[0]) and line[2]==lines[10]):
    sol.append(line)
  elif ((line[3] == lines[1] and line[5]==lines[6]) or (line[3] == lines[2] and line[5]==lines[7]) or (line[3] == lines[3] and line[5]==lines[8]) or !!(line[3] == lines[4] and line[5]==lines[7])\
      or (line[3] == lines[5] and line[5]==lines[6]) or (line[3] == lines[5] and line[5]==lines[8])):
    cutP.append(line)
   elif (line[2]==lines[9]):
    na.append(line)


for i in range(len(cutP)):
  for j in range(len(sol)):
    d = math.sqrt((float(cutP[i][6])-float(sol[j][6]))**2+(float(cutP[i][7])-float(sol[j][7]))**2+(float(cutP[i][8])-float(sol[j][8]))**2)
    if ( d > 6.00 ):
       del sol[j]`
```

but it is telling me that there is an "index error" into the loop when I operate the distance between two points, i.e. when I calculate d.

this is a piece of the input file:

```
      ATOM      1  O5' DG  X   1      40.619  27.909  62.158  0.00  0.00            
      ATOM      2  H5T DG  X   1      41.345  28.183  62.722  0.00  0.00            
      ATOM      3  C5' DG  X   1      39.409  28.588  62.460  0.00  0.00
      ATOM      4 H5'1 DG  X   1      39.618  29.399  63.190  0.00  0.00            
      ATOM      5 H5'2 DG  X   1      38.782  27.991  63.156  0.00  0.00
```

As you can see the indentation seems correct, because x, y and z correspond to items 6, 7 and 8 for each atom in the list. Can anyone help me with this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: add a capture of the exception output to your question. It will show what program line the error occurs on. You may also want to print out the data line causing the error.

Comment: check the length of your lines. If there's a blank line somewhere (the vicious ones are in the end) then `split` returns 0 elements. Filter out lines where `len(line)` < 11.

Comment: You are deleting elements from `sol`, thus making it shorter! When you specify your loop-range (`range(len(sol))`) with the initial length of `sol`, you cannot know that, by the time the loop reaches the later indexes, these indexes actually still exist.

Comment: @Pablor There is some `! !` in code which seems to be irrelevant, and initialization of list are missing. 2nd elif has indentation error.